tesseract cmd works but dotnet doesn't on same tif file
I tested a tif file with Tesseract 5.4.0.20240606 on windows 10 using the command "tesseract test.tif stfdout" and it correctly worked and displayed the associated text.  I put the same tif file into a dotnet c# program and got out gibberish.  I'm assuming that the dotnet setup/configuration in visual studio isn't quite correct.
What changes do I need to get the dotnet version to recognize and interpret correctly. The Dotnet code is attached.
// Load the original bitmap from a file
Bitmap original = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file);
// Create a new bitmap with the desired size
var ocrtext = string.Empty;
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
path = Path.Combine(path, "tessdata");
path = path.Replace("file:\\", "");
var result = "";
// get the ocr data 
using (var ocr = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
{
    ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    {
        using (var img = PixConverter.ToPix(original))
        {
            using (var page = ocr.Process(img))
            {
                ocrtext = page.GetText();
                result = ocrtext.TrimStart('\n');
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outfileab + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.Write("aa:" + result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```


After alot of research, I figured out the whitelist settings were the culprit.  I also changed the enginemode to LSTMONLY and it worked much better.
